# How to transfer data from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have a table say **Table1** in mysql. We have an application that stores data in Table1, millions of new record get saved daily. We have a requirement of extracting data from this table, transform it and then load it to new table say **Table2** (kinda ETL process), which should be happened live in the interval of some seconds. How can i perform it efficiently and without copying duplicate records from Table1.

I though of introducing new field in Table1 say **Extracted** to keep track of extraction. So, if particular row has already been extracted, field **Extracted** will have the value **Y** indicating extraction. If not, then field **Extracted** will have value **N**, which means this row still needs to be extracted. Means ETL job needs to update this field **Extracted** in **Table1** after extraction. What i am wondering is, Would it be efficient to update records in such a huge table where millions of new data get saved daily ?? Please suggest!!

Thank You Guys!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the data in `Table2` in sync (and slighthly modified) with those in `Table1` you have a couple of options on MySQL level:

1. Triggers - create after INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE trigger which transfers the data to `Table2` immediately and does the transformation for you.
2. Views - if data in `Table2` are read only, create a view where select definition does the required transformation.

The advantage of both approaches is that `Table2` is always up to date with `Table1` and no extra fields are required.

Comment: Transfer of data from Table1 to Table2 is to be done from some other process, which reads Table1 data and do some transformations with the help of reading data from some other tables and then finally save to Table2. Table2 is not readonly..

Comment: ok, then triggers might be your option - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html ... you can basically do any operation with the data and the good thing is that it is also transaction scoped (so if your operation on Table1 fails for some reason it is not performed on Table2 as well)

Comment: will go through the link you have provided, thanks for the help michal.jakubeczy!!

Answer (score 0):

use this to ignore duplicate record

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2 (field1,field2) VALUES (x,y);
```

or use this to update record if there is a duplicate record on the table

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (field1,field2) VALUES (x,y) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE primarykey=primarykeyvalues;
```